# Order of resolution with nodejs require module

Tags: node.js, module, coffeescript, require

Suppose I have all of `foo.js`, `foo.coffee`, and `foo.json`in the same directory, and I say `require './foo'` from another (coffeescript) file in that location, what rule governs which one will be loaded?

A short experiment (using `require.resolve './foo'`) would seem to indicate that the javascript file wins over the other two.

Indeed, looking at `require.extensions` it *looks like* `.js` being mentioned there as the first item—but then, object attribute names are inherently unordered in javascript, right?, so any name added to that property could potentially re-order the entries—could that lead to another resolution order?

Just wondering, as i couldn't find any documentation. it does become relevant when you do (and maybe you shouldn't) `coffee --compile route/to/directory`.

Comment: interesting question, have you had any success in attempting to alter your results?

Comment: indeed, yes... see the link given by @loganfsmyth and https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior in V8 is to iterate over named properties in the order they were originally assigned, so I would expect `.js` to always be first.

[This post references that behavior](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer; i marked yours as correct since the link you provided lifts the discussion to a a whole new level—i wasn't aware of most aspects discussed over there.

Comment: This is actually not correct. `.js` is first not because its first element of `Object.keys(require.extensions)`, it's first because it is treated specially. Try to add, say, '.as' to `require.extensions`.

Comment: @AndreySidorov Open to being wrong. Can you give more of an example? I don't follow your `.as` case.

Comment: neither do i. do `d = zzz: yes, bbb: no, '.23': 'decimal', '42': 'integer'; log ( name for name of d ); log Object.keys d; d[ 'bbb' ] = 'reassigned'; log ( name for name of d ); log Object.keys d;` and you'll get `[ '42', 'zzz', 'bbb', '.23' ]` four times. the integer goes to the front (that's v8-special), `bbb` does not budge even when re-assigned.

Answer (score 2):

`.js` is loaded first (this also means that it's better to use full `name.json` for your fixture instead of `name` as it could be shadowed by `name.js`)

From "modules" [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules):

> If the exact filename is not found, then node will attempt to load the required filename with the added extension of .js, .json, and then .node.

Also, read name resolution algorithm in [pseudo-code](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together):

```
LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
1.  If X is a file, load X as JavaScript text.  STOP
2.  If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
3.  If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon.  STOP
```

After (1,2,3) extensions set in require.extensions are checked in the order they a set (for CoffeScript, `require("coffe-script")` [installs](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js#L182-L188) `.coffee` handler).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer; i upvoted it as an attempt to give a 'split vote' (which i can't really do given how things work here on SO). i knew those quotes from the docs but i've always thought they were (1) too unspecific to really be sure how the ordering would be done beyond those known few cases; (2) *much* too short on how to extend the `require` mechanism. note also that while you do correctly quote the above passages from the docs, they're also mildly contradictory, as the pseudocode makes no mention of `.json` files.

Comment: best source of information is `modeule.js` itself - https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js . It's short and easy to read. And documentation does mention .json.

Comment: ah yes, the source... of course... but then we still need a sound documentation on how things are expected to work, right? 'this car can drive at 200 km/h' is different from looking inside a combustion chamber.

Comment: I'd say 'combustion chamber' in your example are V8 internals - lexer, ast parser, optimiser etc. Module.js source here is more like speedometer data - it's actually supposed to be read. And there is proper documentation on how things are expected to work.

Comment: 'there is proper documentation on how things are expected to work' is exactly what i find lacking a tad in this case: the docs are not very specific, the source is not easy to consume, and javascript engines have some sort of a lacunae / white spot in the specs / commonly aggreed-upon set of behaviors (and v8 happens to do it ever so slightly different than the other kids) when it comes to iterating over object keys. javascript is a language supposed to run on many platforms, and nodejs modules are patterned after commonjs, so it is valid to ask what happens to module resolution elsewhere

Comment: That's why module.js does not rely on keys order and explicitly tries (.js .node .json) in that particular order (and this is explained in the documentation). I'm not trying to argue that node.js docs are perfect, I just don't see any missing information in this particular example.